# How does Flare affect a drow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, races

If you successfully cast [flare](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/flare.htm) at a Drow would they be blinded for one round by the bright light (due to being light sensitive) and then dazzled for the rest of the spell's duration (due to the spell's effect)?

Answer (score 6):

**No**, [Drow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/elf.htm#drow) would not be [blinded](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#blinded) for one round by *Flare*, regardless of having *Light Blindness*.

> Light Blindness: Abrupt exposure to bright light (such as sunlight or a daylight spell) blinds drow for 1 round. On subsequent rounds, they are dazzled as long as they remain in the affected area.

[Flare](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/flare.htm) creates a burst of light - it doesn't say *bright light* - simply burst of light. They could still be [dazzled](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#dazzled) by the cantrip though.

**Conjecture**

Given Drow reside in the Underdark, and going topside into the daylight would blind them - think about someone waking you up with all the lights turned on; you literally can't see and are squinting until your eyes adjust. I would cringe to believe that a measly little cantrip would literally blind a drow for a round - especially given the fact that wizards are a favored class for males - and almost every wizard ever made has Light on their spell list.

---

**What is *Bright Light*?**

According to [Vision and Light](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#visionAndLight):

> In an area of bright light, all characters can see clearly. A creature can’t hide in an area of bright light unless it is invisible or has cover.

Examples given on the accompanying table are [Everburning Torch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#everburningTorch), Common Lamp, Bullseye Lantern, Hooded Lantern, [Sunrod](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#sunrod), Torch, [Continual Flame](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/continualFlame.htm), [Dancing Lights](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dancingLights.htm), [Daylight](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/daylight.htm), and [Light](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/light.htm).

The reoccurring theme, especially in the way of spells, is they all produce a minimum amount and brightness of light as a torch does. Flare, unlike the other spells listed, has no mention of bright light, torchlight, and etc.

---

**Commentary**

Dancing Lights actually shocked me a little, because Drow get that as a spell-like ability. But when I really think about it, it doesn't surprise me, because Drow (in 3.5) seem to have a knack of offing each other, and what way better to be sneaky, conniving, and deadly than blinding someone - especially a race that is obsessed with poison use.